# Folders ownerships on Windows and IIS7

Tags: windows, iis, permissions

I've an issue on Godaddy.com Windows (IIS 7) hosting.

I've installed Drupal, and it cannot save some files into specific folders.

I've checked from the control panel, the folder preferences, and they are both writable and readable.

I'm not expert with Windows folders, but I was wondering if I need to change the ownership, to assign them to the webserver (not sure if I can do it with godaddy)

thanks

Comment: Also, the main file is correctly uploaded into another folder (with the same permissions). So it actually doesn't work for images automatically generated by Drupal, not the ones I'm uploading through Drupal php upload script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the ownership, but you'll have to change the folder permissions (access control) to "modify" for the application pool user.